# Server-side encryption with aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

When I’m trying to push objects from Account A to Account B. The destination bucket has

```
“Sid”: “DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads”
 “s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption”:”AES256”,”aws:kms”
```

This the bucket policy for destination s3 bucket.

When I’m trying to push objects using lambda function, it throws following error:

*An error event occurred (Access denied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied*
enter code here
I’ve tried pushing objects to source account with —sse aws:kms and/or —sse AES256. To check whether the data is landing in destination because it has necessary server-side encryption.

Even-though I face the same `Access Denied` error.

```
   {
  "Version":"2008-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Full Access",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:otheriam","arn:aws:iam::444455556666:myrole"]},
      "Action": “s3:*”,
      "Resource":[“arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/”,"arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/*"],
    }
  ]
}
         "Sid":"RequiredEncryptedPuObject",
         "Effect":"Deny",
         "Principal":"*",
         "Action":"s3:PutObject",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket-name/*",
         "Condition":{
            "StringNotEquals":{
               "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption":”AES256”"aws:kms"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You are doing a cross-account copy. The command should be sent to the destination bucket to "pull" the object from the source bucket. Are you sure that you have permissions to `GetObject` from the source bucket _AND_ `PutObject` in the destination bucket? Also, where did you get the quoted configuration — was it from a Bucket Policy? If so, can you show the policy?

Comment: Yes my role is added in the destination bucket, and i have uploaded the bucket policy, it’s kind of messy, using mobile to comment and paste the code.

Comment: I’ve figured the above issue, we need to add s3:GetObjectTagging, s3:PutObjectTagging in the destination bucket